# Não consigo ler os valores retornados do banco utilizando OracleDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

Estou com problema ao ler os valores retornados de um `select`, na linha onde faço:

```
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

no `read` ele me traz os valores corretamente, mas na linha seguinte onde faço `reader.Read()` diz que a enumeração não gerou resultados.

Como resolvo esse problema?

#### Fonte

```
OracleConnection cnn = new OracleConnection(DataFunctions.GetDefaultConnectionString()); OracleCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand(); OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
try
{
    cnn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = cnn;
    cmd.CommandText = String.Format("select * from VI_TESTE where cd_codigo = {0}", code);
    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    // Ao debugar, aqui tem registros

    if (reader.Read())
    {
        // aqui não tem mais registros
        var test1 = reader.GetValue(0);
    }
}
finally
{
    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Tem um registro só ou mais? Quando você debuga, consegue ver até mesmo os valores selecionados?

Comment: Se você verificar `if(reader.HasRows)`, ele retorna `true`?

Comment: @Cigano Morrison Mendez, Possui apenas um registro com 5 campos, no caso cd_codigo é a PK da tabela.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius sim ele retorna true no if(reader.HasRows)

Comment: @filipe_21 Acho inadequado o `reader` para o seu caso. Vou colocar uma resposta.

Comment: Você testou sem estar em debug? Achei uma pergunta semelhante no SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493955/datareader-has-rows-and-data-trying-to-read-from-it-says-no-data-is-present, aparentemente utilizar o debug faz com que o DataReader enumere e não retorne mais resultados quando o código chega no `reader.GetValue(0);`

Comment: @MarcusVinicius Acho que quando ele inspeciona a variável já ocorre a iteração em cima da enumeração. Por isso a enumeração entra vazia dentro do `if`.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Exatamente o que eu pensei, vamos esperar a resposta dele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A abordagem por `OracleDataReader` possivelmente vai te trazer problemas na inspeção. Para o seu caso, use apenas `OracleDataAdapter` conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
using (var cnn = new OracleConnection(DataFunctions.GetDefaultConnectionString())) 
{
    var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand(); 

    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("select * from VI_TESTE where cd_codigo = {0}", code);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        // Inspecione aqui ds
    }
    finally
    {
        cnn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mergulhando no ds indo em DataSet > non public members > tableCollection > result view > rows > result view > itemArray[5] estão os valores que preciso,
mas indo em Ralations > result view > ocorre a mensagem que aparece para o getValue e getString "A enumeração não gerou resultados"

Comment: Isto não é problema. O objetivo não é recuperar os valores? Se sim, você pode ler os valores do `DataSet` sem problemas.

Comment: Agora lendo via dataSet não ocorre mas o problema, valeu muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o método GetString ao invés de GetValue.

O comando Read verifica se há mais uma linha, havendo ele avança para a linha seguinte e retorna true.
De acordo com a documentação da [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx), o dataReader começa sempre antes da primeira linha de dados, portanto você pode executar o Read antes de começar a ler (exatamente como você fez).
Já o método GetValue, conforme a documentação da [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) retorna o objeto em seu formato nativo. Talvez o campo esteja nulo ou ele não esteja conseguindo fazer a conversão, e por isso dá erro.

Comment: ambos o GetValue e GetString estouram o erro de "a enumeração não gerou resultados" tanto dentro como fora dos if do Read() e HasRows que retornam true, e o GetName funciona normal retornando o nome da coluna.